# Arrays dosen't seem to work correctly in ProcessingJS

Tags: arrays, processing, processing.js

I'm making a game currently for fun, and wanted to use arrays to draw levels with.

However, it seems there is some error that stops the program from actually drawing the rectangles. I've looked for pretty much every error that I could think of in the code. I've even tried re-learning the array subject on KhanAcademy, but nothing there seems to fix my problem. So I thought that StackOverflow was my last resort. [You can see the game here](http://tufda.net/processingjs/JUMPER/launch_game.html), or if you just wanna see the pure code, [it can be found here](http://tufda.net/processingjs/JUMPER/game.js), and if you think my site will give you a virus, you can just see it here:

```javascript
    var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
    with (processingInstance) {
        size(400, 400);
        frameRate(60);      

        // Setup stuff 'n stuff
            noStroke();
            fill(0, 0, 0);
            var scene = 0;
            var controlsEnable = 0;
            var tufdasDebug = 0;
            var tufdasLeve;

        /* Key/control variables (JavaScript key codes:
        http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)*/
            var keyIsPressed = 0;
            var key_SHIFT = 16;
            var key_CTRL = 17;

        // Position & Size variables
            var jumperXPos = 100;
            var jumperYPos = 360;
            var jumperSize = 20;

        // Counters
            var jumperXCounter = 11;
            var jumperYCounter = 11;
            var shiftCounter = 11;

        keyPressed = function() {
            keyIsPressed = 1;
        };

        keyReleased = function() {
            keyIsPressed = 0;
            resetCounters();
        };

        var askForResolution = function() {
            text("What resolution do you want to play in?", 100, 15);
        };

        var addCounters = function(amount) {
            if (amount) {
                jumperXCounter += amount;
                jumperYCounter += amount;
                shiftCounter += amount;
            } else {
                jumperXCounter ++;
                jumperYCounter ++;
                shiftCounter ++;
            }
        };

        var resetCounters = function() {
            jumperXCounter = 11;
            jumperYCounter = 11;
            shiftCounter = 11;
        };
        var controlsHandler = function() {
            addCounters();

            if (tufdasDebug === 1) { console.log("Handling controls..."); }
            if (keyIsPressed === 1) {
                if (tufdasDebug === 1) { console.log("A key is being pressed..."); }
                if (controlsEnable === 0) {
                    if (tufdasDebug === 1) { console.log("Controls disabled..."); }
                    if (keyCode === key_SHIFT) {
                        if (tufdasDebug === 1) { console.log("Shift is being pressed."); }
                        scene ++;
                        controlsEnable = 1;
                    }
                } else if (controlsEnable === 1) {
                    if (keyCode === UP && jumperYCounter > 10) {
                        jumperYPos -= 20;
                        jumperYCounter = 0;
                    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT && jumperXCounter > 10) {
                        jumperXPos += 20;
                        jumperXCounter = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var drawIntroSequence = function(y) {
            textSize(30);
            text("JUMPER", 125, y + 100);
            textSize(15);
            text("Press SHIFT or RSHIFT to continue...\n(make sure to click inside the game first)", 65, y + 300);
        };

        var drawJumper = function() {
            fill(0, 0, 255);
            rect(jumperXPos, jumperYPos, jumperSize, jumperSize);

        };

        var drawtufdasLevel = function() {
            fill(0, 0, 0);
            rect(tufdasLevel[0], tufdasLevel[1], tufdasLevel[2], tufdasLevel[3]);
            rect(tufdasLevel[4], tufdasLevel[5], tufdasLevel[6], tufdasLevel[7]);
        };






        draw = function() {
            background(255, 255, 255);
            if (scene === 0) {
                drawIntroSequence(0);
                var tufdasLevel = [0, 380, 400, 20, 0, 0, 400, 20]; // Space indicates a new command.
            } else if (scene === 1) {
                drawtufdasLevel();
                drawJumper();
            }
            controlsHandler();
        };
}};
var canvas = document.getElementById("tufdaDrawCanvas");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out exactly what's happening, open up your JavaScript console by opening your game in a browser, pressing the F12 key, and then going to the "Console" tab.

When your game starts, you'll see the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at game.js:100`

That tells you the error is happening on line 100 of your sketch, which is this line:

```javascript
rect(tufdasLevel[0], tufdasLevel[1], tufdasLevel[2], tufdasLevel[3]);
```

So now you know something is wrong with your `tufdasLevel` variable. Let's see where you **declare** it. You've got one here on line 12:

```javascript
var tufdasLevel;
```

That's your declaration, but where is your initialization? You've got one here, one line 118:

```javascript
var tufdasLevel = [0, 380, 400, 20, 0, 0, 400, 20]; // Space indicates a new command.
```

Ah-ha! Notice how you're using the **var** keyword to declare **another** variable named `tufdasLevel`. This is a **different** variable from the one at the top of your sketch, which is the one being used on line 100. The `tufdasLevel` variable on line 118 is **never used**, and the `tufdasLevel` on line 12 is **never initialized**. So when your game tries to use that uninitialized variable, you get the error you're seeing.

It seems like you meant to **initialize** the variable on line 118, **not declare it**. Try just dropping the `var` keyword from line 118:

```javascript
tufdasLevel = [0, 380, 400, 20, 0, 0, 400, 20]; // Space indicates a new command.
```

You might also put that initialization on line 12 instead.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! That was a very elaborate answer, and I am very happy to recieve it. You suggested putting the initialization on line 12, does that speed the game up or do anything at all? Once again, thanks very much :D

Comment: @tufda I doubt you'll notice any speed difference. But think about when you want stuff to happen- the initialization of `tufdasLevel` only needs to happen **once**. In your code, it'll happen 60 times per second while the intro screen is showing. It just makes more sense to put it at the beginning of the sketch, so it only happens once.